# Unicode displaying inconsistently when escaped in JS vs HTML

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I'm trying to insert a musical coda symbol into a `<p>` element with JavaScript, but it's showing up incorrectly. The musical symbol shows up completely fine when it's HTML-escaped however. What is the reason for this inconsistency?

http://jsfiddle.net/4m3kLtk5/3/

PS: It happens on Chrome and Firefox on my Mac, but I haven't yet had the chance to test it on any other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `x.innerHTML = '\uD834\uDD0C';` this should work. The code for the character should be `\uD834\uDD0C` instead of `\u1d10c`

Comment: Ahhh yes. After more reading I see that JavaScript uses UTF-16 by default, so that explains it. Thanks!